# How can I identify my PC's ethernet interface name for filtering

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, traffic

I want to define a capture filter as in this example:

```
tcpdump -ni eth0 "tcp port 443 and (tcp[((tcp[12] & 0xf0) >> 2)] = 0x16)"
```

Now the example uses `eth0`. How can I know what is my PC's interface name?

Comment: Your question is a non-sequitur.  Nothing in that tcpdump filter has anything to do with figuring out your MAC address or local interface name...

Comment: what about `eth0`?

Comment: Alrighty, you know, I was focused on the BPF filter.  To find out your adapter name, why not try "ifconfig -a" or "ifstat"